# When querying and populating subdocuments, how can I detect and handle subdocuments that were deleted?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Data Model that contains an array of ObjectIDs for another Data Model.

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
  images: {
    type: [{
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Image'
    }],
    default: []
  },
});
```

When I query `Products` and populate `Image` records, how can I detect when some Image records have been deleted?

Comment: Rhetorically, what happens when you try to populate deleted documents into a parent? Can you use that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that some of the images in your array might have had it's object removed so you want to check for that. What you can do is to check this in the save hook, something like this:

```
ProductSchema
    .pre('save', function(next) {
        var Image = mongoose('Image');
        this.images.forEach(function(image) {
            Image.objects.findById(image, function(err, image) {
                if (!image) {
                    // This would mean the object has been removed so 
                    // the saved id is missing a reference...
                    ...
                }
            })
        })
        next();
    });
```

Comment: @ac360 did this help any?